# MySQL query from data normalized tables

Tags: mysql

I have three tables:

users

```
user_id    username
---------------------
1        |  mrzander  
2        |  foo
3        |  bar
---------------------
```

interests

```
interest_id    interest
------------------------
1            |  cars
2            |  power tools
3            |  shaving
4            |  phones
5            |  computers
------------------------
```

user_interests

```
id    uid    iid
-----------------
1   |  1   |  2
2   |  1   |  4
3   |  2   |  3
4   |  1   |  5
-----------------
```

Basically, I have a table of users, a table of interests, and a table that shows what users have what interests. If I know what user id I want the interests from, what query would give me all of a particular users interests?

In this example, what query would return a table called "Interests" that tells me user_id = 1 likes power tools, phones, and computers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the result on same row you should use join and group concat

```
select c.username, group_concat( b.interst)
from user_interest as a
left join interest as b on a.iid = b.interest_id
left join users as c. on c.user_id = a.uid
where  c.user_id = 1
group by c.username
```

or if you need result on different rows se join only

```
select c.username,  b.interst
from user_interest as a
left join interest as b on a.iid = b.interest_id
left join users as c. on c.user_id = a.uid
where  c.user_id = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply join the two tables.

```
select i.*
from interests i
join user_interests u
on u.iid = i.interest_id
where i.uid = 1;
```